# Mysql: grouping digit regardless of the digit's position

Tags: mysql, sql

This sounds a little bit confusing and I don't know how to put it in words, but I'm having a hard time finding a solution of this problem.

I want to 'group by' the rows and count them in the table using the 'digit' column that has the same digits regardless of the digit's position.

example:

this is the table

| Id | Name | Digit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | 123 |
| 2 | name2 | 213 |
| 3 | name3 | 132 |
| 4 | name4 | 122 |
| 5 | name5 | 456 |

the answer would be: with count()

| Name | Digit | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 123 | 3 |
| name4 | 122 | 1 |
| name5 | 456 | 1 |

additional details:

- the digit column is numeric
- length fixed(3)
- the 'name' column display must be any from the group (could be name1, name2, or name3)

mysql version is 82 from cpanel.

Comment: Why you delete [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66777571/group-digit-that-has-same-digit-regardless-of-the-digits-position?noredirect=1#comment118043066_66777571)? *mysql version is 82 from cpanel.* Such version not exists. Execute `SELECT VERSION();` and provide complete output.

Comment: I suggest storing a sorted version of each `Digit` value at the time when you write out each record.  Do this from your application layer, where it is much easier to handle.  Swinging this from MySQL is going to be fairly ugly (and non performant).

Comment: Does zero `0` is present in the values? Does it may be (formally) leading?

Comment: 1+2+3 = 2+1+3=3+2+1 etc = 6

Comment: Is it always 3 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think the single digits of the `Digit` column as coordinates in a 3D space. If the coordinates are swapped the resulting vector will have the same lenght.  You can use this property to create an efficient query:

```
SELECT Name, Digit, COUNT(*) as C
FROM t
GROUP BY(
    POW(CAST(SUBSTRING(digit, 1, 1) AS UNSIGNED),2) +   -- first digit
    POW(CAST(SUBSTRING(digit, 2, 1) AS UNSIGNED),2) +   -- second digit
    POW(CAST(SUBSTRING(digit, 3, 1) AS UNSIGNED),2)     -- third digit
);
```

I don't calculate the square root because we are not interested in the exact length. I named the column `c` instead of `count` because `COUNT` is reserved word in SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer sir...it's very understandable and simple for my level of familiarity in sql

Comment: No problem... I'm here to help.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH 
parsed AS ( SELECT id, name, Digit DIV 100 val FROM test
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id, name, Digit MOD 100 DIV 10 FROM test
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id, name, Digit MOD 10 FROM test ),
sorted AS ( SELECT id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(val ORDER BY val SEPARATOR '') Digit
            FROM parsed
            GROUP BY id, name )
SELECT MIN(name) Name, Digit, COUNT(*) `Count`
FROM sorted
GROUP BY Digit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int,name varchar(20),digit int);
insert into t values
(1, 'name1',    123),
(2, 'name2',    213),
(3, 'name3',    132),
(4, 'name4',    122),
(5, 'name5',    456),
(6, 'name5',    77),
(7, 'name5',    1),
(8, 'name5',    1);

    with cte as
    (
    select distinct substring(digit,1,1) + substring(digit,2,1) + substring(digit,3,1) digit from t
    )
    select min(id) id,min(name) name,min(t.digit) digit,count(*) cnt
    from   cte
    join   t on   substring(t.digit,1,1) + substring(t.digit,2,1) + substring(t.digit,3,1) = cte.digit
    group  by cte.digit;

+------+-------+-------+-----+
| id   | name  | digit | cnt |
+------+-------+-------+-----+
|    7 | name5 |     1 |   2 |
|    4 | name4 |   122 |   1 |
|    1 | name1 |   123 |   3 |
|    6 | name5 |    77 |   1 |
|    5 | name5 |   456 |   1 |
+------+-------+-------+-----+
5 rows in set, 15 warnings (0.002 sec)
```